# Pandas. Matching values with corresponding ranges from other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes.

The first one contains user ids and their score (points column). Another dataframe contains some thresholds and range name.

I need to create a new column in the first df which will be the range from the second df if the value from points column is between 'lower' and 'upper' thresholds.

[image][image]

I tried to use the following code:

```
def r(points):
r = thresholds #thresholds is the df from my second screenshot
if r['lower'] <= points < r['upper']:
    r['range']
return r['range']

PointsEarned['range'] = PointsEarned.points.map(r)
```

However I get an error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I guess that I need to use some loops here to iterate over thresholds dataframe.

Any help on how to create a new 'range' column will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and bins are created from `upper` column with inserting first value of `lower` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'upper': [25,50,75,100,150,250],
                        'lower': [1,25, 50,75,100,150]})

PointsEarned = pd.DataFrame(data={'points': [32,6,80,113]})

bins = np.insert(df['upper'].values, 0, df['lower'].iat[0])
print (bins)
[  1  25  50  75 100 150 250]

PointsEarned['range'] = pd.cut(PointsEarned.points, bins=bins, right=False)

print (PointsEarned)
   points       range
0      32    [25, 50)
1       6     [1, 25)
2      80   [75, 100)
3     113  [100, 150)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. This might help other people. You can actually build tables in sqlite and use a join to match up the ranges.

```
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy.pool

sqlite = sqlalchemy.pool.manage(sqlite3, poolclass=sqlalchemy.pool.SingletonThreadPool)
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:") 
A = pd.DataFrame(data={'points': [32,6,80,113,57,48,5,28,10,11,29,125]})
B = pd.DataFrame(data={'lower': [1,25, 50,75,100,150],
                       'upper': [25,50,75,100,150,250],                        
                       'range': ['[1,25]','[25,50]', '[50,75]','[75,100]','[100,150]','[150,250]']})

A.to_sql("A", conn, index=False)
B.to_sql("B", conn, index=False)
qry = "SELECT points,  lower, upper, range   FROM A left join B on A.points between B.lower and B.upper"
tt = pd.read_sql_query(qry,conn)
print tt
```